# Create a new Actor with Location in Gridworld

Tags: java, gridworld

I want to create a Gridworld with one "Car"-actor and a fix spawn location:

```
      package gridworld.blatt3;
    import gridworld.framework.actor.*;
    import gridworld.framework.grid.Grid;
    import gridworld.framework.grid.Location;
    
    public class Traffic {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            TrafficWorld world = new TrafficWorld();
            System.out.println("Anwendung startet...");
            Location loc1 = new Location(0,0);
            Grid.put(loc1, new Car());
            world.show();
        }
    }
    package gridworld.framework.actor;

import gridworld.framework.actor.bugs.Flower;
import gridworld.framework.grid.Grid;
import gridworld.framework.grid.Location;

import java.awt.*;

public class Car extends AbstractActor {
    //Schrittgröße//
    int speed=5;
    int sideLenght=50;
    int step = 0;


    //Richtung //
    public Car () {
    setDirection(Location.EAST);
    setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    public void act () {
       move();
    }

    public void move() {
        int speedCount=0;
        //Springt immer um 'speed'-Schritte //
        do {
            step++;
        speedCount++;
            if (step < sideLenght) {
                System.out.println("Step: "+step);
                Location loc = getLocation();
                Location next = loc.getAdjacentLocation(getDirection());
                moveTo(next);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("car drives off the grid");
                removeSelfFromGrid();
                break;
            }

        } while (speedCount!=speed);
    }

}



   package gridworld.framework.actor;

import gridworld.framework.grid.BoundedGrid;

public class TrafficWorld extends ActorWorld {
    private static final int rowSize = 1;
    private static final int colSize = 50;

    public TrafficWorld() {
        super(new BoundedGrid<Actor>(rowSize, colSize));
    }
}
```

How can I define a specific spawn location for "Car"? E.g. I want the Actors to spawn in the top left corner of the Grid, I created a Location object "loc1" to use with Grid.put(), but I get an error: java: non-static method put(gridworld.framework.grid.Location,E) cannot be referenced from a static context

I'm using openjdk-15.0.1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: You are trying to use `Grid.put()` like a static method call, but `gridworld.framework.grid.Grid<T>` is an interface. Also, the source code of `TrafficWorld` is missing. Also explain which library you are using and in which version.

Comment: right, I added the missing details. I dont know how to use an interface, I'll learn that and try again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`ActorWorld.add()`](https://horstmann.com/gridworld/javadoc/info/gridworld/actor/ActorWorld.html#add(info.gridworld.grid.Location,%20info.gridworld.actor.Actor)) method with the `Location` argument to place the actor at a specific location:

> **add**
>
> `public void add(Location loc, Actor occupant)`
>
> Adds an actor to this world at a given location.

In your case it would be something like:

```
world.add(new Location(0, 0), new Car());
```